# php increasing the size of the file when you save if the file has not been changed

Tags: php, file, fopen, filesize

If you know the size of the file function `filesize($file_path)` 
it will have a size `A bytes`.

Open the file and output the contents in `textarea`. 
Without making any changes, save it:

If you then open the file

```
$save_file = fopen($file_path, 'w'); 
if ($save_file) 
{
   // Write new data to a file 
   $do_write = fwrite ($save_file, stripslashes ($_POST['file'])); 

   if ($do_write) 
   {
     $message = "Success"; 
   } 
   else 
   {
     $message = "Error"; 
   } 
} 
else 
{
  $message = "Error"; 
}
```

Look again at the file size function `filesize($file_path)` it will have size `B bytes`. 
Where `A < B`.

Problem: Why do I get the size of the file if the file itself and its contents have not been altered?

Comment: whitespace, new lines - could be anything. the filesize wont change unless something is altered in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a file with the `'w'` permission will append to the file if it already has content. Also keep in mind that the length of the file name effects the number of bytes a file uses.

For example, backing up `file.ext` as `file.ext.bak` will make `file.ext.bak` 3 bytes longer.

Comment: You're confusing the `'w'` permission (which empties the file before writing to it) with the `'a'` permission (which writes the new content at the end of the file).

Answer (score 0):

You may be adding whitespace to the file and not know it. I would try and track the changes with git and see what is changing. You can also [do a `diff` in shell](http://xmodulo.com/2012/12/how-to-diff-remote-files-over-ssh.html). a A good way to check if a file has changed without checking the filesize is by hashing it. Here is what you do:

```
$hash = hash_file('md5', '/internal/path/to/file.txt');

// Code to store hash code in database/file.
```

Then to check if it has changed do the same thing and compare it to the stored hash. This will be more reliable than filesize since meta-data (name, extension, permissions) on the file could change filesize and leave the file contents unchanged.